# peak fitting lmfit nan outcome

Tags: python-2.7, lmfit

trying to fit a peak to some data like this:

```
import scipy
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
x = shm.PTR_P
y = shm.PORE_V_P
mod = LorentzianModel()

pars = mod.guess(y, x=x)
out  = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
```

and while I can do the fit if I generate the data, if I try to read them from another source it doesn't work. Am not too good at this and have no idea what the issue is. Here is the output:

> [x,y]
>   [(34.145490000000002, 3.4599999999999999e-08),
>    (29.286449999999999, 4.8399999999999997e-08),
>    (25.118860000000002, 0.026773140000000001),
>    (21.544350000000001, 0.068791409999999997),
>    (18.4785, 0.083200979999999994),
>    (15.848929999999999, 0.02123179),
>    (11.659139999999999, 0.01551077),
>    (10.0, 0.084493879999999993),
>    (6.3095739999999996, 2.0899999999999998e-07),
>    (5.4116949999999999, 0.045209140000000002),
>    (4.6415889999999997, 0.054789360000000002),
>    (3.4145489999999996, 8.9399999999999993e-08),
>    (2.9286449999999999, 0.01100814),
>    (2.5118860000000001, 0.088990659999999999),
>    (1.84785, 3.5799999999999995e-07),
>    (1.5848930000000001, 0.099999009999999999),
>    (1.359356, 0.075139280000000003),
>    (1.1659139999999999, 0.167379),
>    (1.0, 0.57693050000000001),
>    (0.85769590000000007, 1.8658159999999999),
>    (0.73564230000000008, 8.4961369999999992),
>    (0.6309574, 25.299099999999999),
>    (0.54116949999999997, 21.413350000000001),
>    (0.46415889999999999, 13.408829999999998),
>    (0.39810719999999999, 8.3584750000000003),
>    (0.34145490000000006, 5.3982010000000002),
>    (0.29286440000000002, 3.7518540000000002),
>    (0.25118859999999998, 2.5325389999999999),
>    (0.21544349999999998, 1.7722470000000001),
>    (0.18478499999999998, 1.445808),
>    (0.15848929999999997, 1.182083),
>    (0.13593559999999999, 0.94957730000000007),
>    (0.1165914, 0.67620849999999999),
>    (0.10000000000000001, 0.46631620000000001),
>    (0.085769590000000007, 0.41001890000000002),
>    (0.07356422, 0.30625920000000001),
>    (0.063095730000000003, 0.24040219999999998),
>    (0.054116949999999997, 0.1942596),
>    (0.046415890000000001, 0.11306760000000002),
>    (0.039810720000000001, 0.099998470000000006),
>    (0.034145490000000001, 0.099998470000000006),
>    (0.029286449999999999, 0.02246857),
>    (0.025118870000000001, 0.077529909999999994)]

Comment: Usually you get NAN's or INF's when your data you are trying to fit is too far from your distribution. Maybe try with another (or modify yours so that your Gaussian is proportional to your scale). Check also the `nan_to_num()` functions; it helped me once when I could not get rid of NAN's and INF's

Comment: Are you sure that is the output?  A fit report should not look like that, and I don't see any NaNs in it.

Comment: hi, tried this as well without any success...  but i believe the problem is the data format...

Comment: here's an example of output "[[Model]]
    Model(lorentzian)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 8003
    # data points      = 43
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = nan
    reduced chi-square = nan
    Akaike info crit   = nan
    Bayesian info crit = nan
[[Variables]]
    sigma:       nan        +/- nan      (nan%) (init= 0)
    center:      nan        +/- nan      (nan%) (init= 0.5454286)
    amplitude:   nan        +/- nan      (nan%) (init=-5.274815)
    fwhm:        nan        +/- 0        (nan%)  == '2.0000000*sigma'

Comment: i did get it working by fixing the parameter ranges:gauss1  = GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
pars.update( gauss1.make_params())

pars['g1_center'].set(-1, min= -3, max=1)
pars['g1_sigma'].set(0.4, min=0.03)
pars['g1_amplitude'].set(2, min=1)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that either there are NaNs in your data or that the initial guess is so far off as to produce NaNs.    The initial guess of 0 for `sigma` seems suspicious -- this should be > 0. 
Either way, plotting the data and using `np.isnan()` would probably help isolate the problem.